# How to set multiple values for the css property outline?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, outline

I am using IE11 to render one of my dialog boxes, so along with the default dotted border which is the existing style for the button in focus, is there anyway I could add one more value for the outline attribute like below:

```css
input[type=button]:focus{
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

Adding it this way is actually replacing the default outline value which is set by IE so I just wanted to know if getting both is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add relevant HTML to your snippet and expected output - for example a screenshot or drawing

Comment: Your description is a little bit confusing. You were talking about border and outline. Border and outline both are different. Outline get display outside the element content. do you mean that you want to display 2 kinds of outline like dotted and solid together? If yes, it is not possible. you can assign the only one type of style at a time. Please correct me, if I am misunderstanding here. You can try to provide more information about the issue that may help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Outline has some degree of customization, you can even have double borders.

This MDN page has some nice examples of the different styles you can have.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

```html
<button style="outline: thick double #32a1ce;">Foo</button>
```

```html
<button style="outline: 8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .6);">Foo</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`outline` can take till 3 properties which are similar as `border`.

```
 outline-width
 outline-style
 outline-color
```

I tested it in all browser and it seems to work fine:

```css
input[type=button]:focus{
  outline: 8px solid rgba(170, 50, 220, .6);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
```